# How to crop plot area to the exact range of your data in R?

Tags: r, plot

When I set limits to a plot in R, there is some distance between the limits I set and the actual limits of the plot area:

```
plot(c(1, 4), c(1, 4), ylim = c(1, 4))
```

[image]

Of course I can set the limits *inside the outermost ticks* so they appear to fall close to the edge of the plot area. I can get pretty close by drawing the axis separately and allowing it to be drawn outside the plot area:

```
plot(c(1, 4), c(1, 4), ylim = c(1.2, 3.8), axes = FALSE)
par(xpd = TRUE)
abline(h = 4, col = "grey")  # just to show the edge of the box
axis(2, at=c(1, 4), labels = c(1, 4))
```

[image]

But that's just eyeballing it. So:

**How can I get the outermost ticks to fall *exactly* on the border of the plot area?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`xaxs = 'i'` and `yaxs = 'i'` in the plot statement will cause it to fit the data exactly for the x and y axes respectively ([details](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/graphics/html/par.html)).

Answer (score 2):

The plot parameters `xaxs` and `yaxs` help with this:

```
plot(c(1, 4), c(1, 4), xaxs="i")
```